# returning the highest sum of digits in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there a good way to loop over this to get it to return the number that has the highest sum of it's digits? so, "333" should be what is logged, rather than "9".

```
var myArr = [ '111' , '222' , '333' ];
var result = myArr.map(function(text){
  return text.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(x, y){
    return +y + x;
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: This is for javascript.

Comment: This is JavaScript; I've just edited the question to add the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired output is just a single number from the source array you don't need the `.map()` function. You can use `.reduce()` to compare the sums of the digits of each number, but return the original numbers:

```js
const sumDigits = n => (String(n).match(/\d/g)||[]).reduce((x,y) => +x + +y, 0);
const numWithLargestSum = arr =>
  arr.reduce((a, c) => sumDigits(a||0) >= sumDigits(c) ? a : c, null);

const myArr = [ '111' , '222' , '333' ];

console.log(numWithLargestSum(myArr));                // 333
console.log(numWithLargestSum([]));                   // null
console.log(numWithLargestSum(['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'])); // 4779-252888-3972
console.log(numWithLargestSum(['123', '111', '321', ''])); // 123
```

Notes:

- If more than one number has the same sum, the above will return the *first*. If you want to return the *last* simply change the `>=` comparison to `>`.
- If the array is empty it will return `null`. I'm passing `null` as the initial value for the `.reduce()` operation but then using `||0` to convert that to a `0`, but for empty arrays that bit doesn't run.
- I've used the `.match(/\d/g)` from the question because in a comment you were talking about input strings like `4779-252888-3972`, but if an item had no digits `.match()` would return `null` so I've used `||[]` to guard against that in order to just call `.reduce()` on the result within my `sumDigits()` function. Easier than adding in an `if`.

Comment: This is **eloquent.** Among the infinity possible ways to achieve it, this, having the perfect amount of abstraction, is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the sloppiness, but what about something like this?

This approach uses a variable that is compared against in a loop to find the highest **total**, while simultaneously making use of a second variable to store the highest **string** representation.

```js
var myArr = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];
var highest_string = 0;
var highest_total = 0;

function add(string) {
  string = string.replace(/-/g, "").split('');
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(string[i], 10);
  }
  return sum;
}

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  if(add(myArr[i]) > highest_total) {
    highest_string = myArr[i];
    highest_total = add(myArr[i]);
  }
  // Also log matchers
  else if (add(myArr[i]) == highest_total) {
    console.log(myArr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(highest_string);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: it sure does. though is there a way to keep the regex from my example in there?

Comment: There would be a way, yes... though it's not really necessary given the above structure. Your regex `/\d/g` matches against digits, which is essentially the same as `parseInt()` -- it only accepts integers that are extracted from the string. You could use `sum += string[i].match(/\d/g);` instead of `sum += parseInt(string[i], 10);` if you really wanted :)

Comment: when i pass this array ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260']  it comes up undefined?

Comment: @yupyupyup -- Well spotted! I've fixed the above code by adding `string.replace(/-/g, "")`  before splitting the string (on the first line of `add`). I've also included your sample array to showcase the fix :)

Comment: two of the numbers in the array have the same total. is there a good way to make it log the second of the two? in this scenario it logs the first.

Comment: @yupyupyup -- No problem, and there sure is! Simply log the index of the array if it matches the highest total when passed through the function. The second number is the `console.log` inside my `else if`. The first number is the `console.log` isolated at the bottom. I've logged both in my above snippet :)

Comment: sry whats that look like exactly

Comment: Sorry, what's **what** look like? I've updated the snippet above; you can see it in action there -- the `else if` code is simply: `else if (add(myArr[i]) == highest_total) { console.log(myArr[i]); }` if that's what you're referring to?

Comment: oh i meant if theres a way for it to only log the second

Comment: Yes; simply remove the final (isolated) `console.log`.

Comment: how exactly does the "highest total" variable work here? it is eqaul to 0, so shouldnt all the numbers be greater than it? i guess Im unsure how this program figures out which number adds up to be the largest sum.

Comment: @yupyupyup - In the `for` loop, I have the condition `if(add(myArr[i]) > highest_total) { highest_total = add(myArr[i]); }`. The `if` statement runs the `add()` function for each of the strings, and returns their total. If it's greater than `highest_total` (`0` by default), it **assigns** this number to `highest_total`. Therefor, when the loop reaches the **second** number, `highest_total` is equal to the total of the **first** string's digits. If the second total is higher than the first, `highest_total` becomes the **second** total. If not, it stays as the **first** total. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArr = [ '111' , '222' , '333'];
var result = myArr.map(function(text){
  var num = text.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') || '0';
  
  return new Function("return " + num.split("").join("+"))();
});
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, result);
var index = result.indexOf(max);

console.log("highest------",myArr[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this,

```js
 Array.prototype.max = function() {
      return Math.max.apply(null, this);
    };
    var myArr = [ '111' , '222' , '333' ];
    var result = myArr.map(function(text){
      return text.split('').reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
    });
    console.log(result);
    console.log(Math.max.apply(null, result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArr = ['111', '222', '444', '333'];

var indexOfMaxValue = myArr.map(function(str){
  return str.split("").reduce((x,y) => +x + +y, 0);
}).reduce((max, x, i, arr) => x > arr[max] ? i : max, 0);

console.log("indexOfMaxValue: " , indexOfMaxValue, ", the original value was: ", myArr[indexOfMaxValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let f = s => s.split('').reduce((a, b) => +b+a || a, 0);

document.write( ["1-2", "3-4"].reduce((a, b) => f(a) > f(b) ? a : b) );       // "3-4"
```